# Malloc fails when linking against exe

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

Using Visual Studio 2015 I have two projects in one solution.  One project is always built as an EXE.  It calls a function in a second project.  The second project can be compiled as either an EXE or a DLL.

If the second project is compiled as a DLL then everything works correctly.  If the second project is compiled as an EXE then the `new` in the second project crashes when it attempts to call `malloc`.

Can anyone explain why this fails when the second project is built as an EXE?

EXE:

```
__declspec(dllimport) void func();
int main()
{
   new char[8];
   func();
   return 0;
}
```

DLL or EXE:

```
__declspec(dllexport) void func()
{
   new char[8];
}

int main()
{
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is the first EXE loading the second EXE like a DLL? If so, that won't work.

Comment: I believe so.  It isn't using the APIs to dynamically load it like a DLL, but it is linking against a .lib generated from the .exe.

Comment: I thought that the difference between an exe and a dll was a single flag in the PE header.  From that understanding I assumed that it should work.

Comment: The C and C++ runtime libraries use completely different module-local startup code for DLLs and for EXEs.  At a minimum:  If you're statically linking the Visual C++ libraries, then the C runtime will not be initialized in the EXE module when it is loaded as a DLL.  The heap won't be initialized, so dynamic memory allocation via `malloc` or `operator new` won't work. I don't know what will happen if the Visual C++ libraries DLLs are used. (I've never tried any of this, so there may be other, potentially more fundamental, problems as well.)

Comment: "dll or exe" makes no sense.  For a code library, you can load it dynamically (dll), or statically (lib).  If you compile it as a lib, then you will need to specify it as a dependency in the project file.  However none of this makes any sense if it is crashing on new char [8].  Maybe you are trying to link library code built under a different runtime library.  That could work with a dll, but fail under static linking.

Comment: Visual Studio seems to be happy to let you do that, so long as you export symbols.  However, malloc points to an entry in a jump table that points to some random location.

Comment: When you build an exe or a dll that exports symbols it also generates a .lib that can be linked against that just tells it to load the .dll.  So, I build an exe or a dll, and then link against the .lib that is generated in connection with the exe or dll.

Comment: James: They are compiled using /MDd.